# Wordpress: strtotime() возвращает вчерашний день

Tags: php, wordpress, дата

Есть задача подтянуть на сайт прогноз погоды с Яндекса. Дата там выводится в формате `<time class="time forecast-briefly__date" datetime="2021-10-22 00:00+0300">22 окт</time>`.

1. Заношу в $date значение атрибута datetime "2021-10-22 00:00+0300"
2. Дату в виде "день.месяц" получаю с помощью `date('d.m', strtotime($date))`
3. День недели, соответственно, через `strftime('%a', strtotime($date))`

На тестовой обычной php-странице (без движка) всё выводится и отображается корректно: `22.10, Fri`. Но когда переношу этот код на главную страницу сайта под Wordpress, то получаю вчерашний день: `21.10, Thu` (все остальные данные подтягиваются правильно, на сегодняшнюю дату).

Проблема, конечно, решается прибавлением суток к дате `strtotime($date)+86400`, но это явный "костыль".

Подскажите, почему в Wordpress'е некорректно отрабатывает `strtotime($date)`? И, может быть, есть какой-то другой способ получения нужных мне данных из datetime="2021-10-22 00:00+0300"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция date в WordPress не рекомендуется к использованию, потому что в зависимости от установок часового пояса может выдавать неверные результаты. Если бы вы пользовались Code Sniffer и стандартами кодирования WPCS, вы бы получили предупреждение ещё на этапе написания кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам надо использовать функцию `wp_date()`. Ниже пример кода с date и wp_date на сайте, где в качестве timezone установлено UTC+3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас только обратил внимание, что с Вашим решением дата стала сегодняшней, а день недели остался вчерашним :(( С решением @ЕгорБанин меняются оба параметра.

Comment: @Danila как я понимаю надо просто использовать `wp_date('d.m D')`. [D](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php) -- день недели.

Comment: Ответ конечно верный, но это уже не php а wordpress-программирование :-) Какая же жесть там внутри: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L227

Comment: @ЕгорБанин вопрос в первую очередь по WordPress, а не php.

Comment: @Danila где код, которым вы выводите день недели?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, *strftime('%a', strtotime($date))* (в вопросе см. п.3)

Comment: @KAGGDesign, в принципе вариант с `wp_date('d.m D')` работает, но есть проблема: мне надо отдельно дату и отдельно день недели (потому что они по вёрстке в разных местах). День недели вот так `wp_date('D')` не выводится.

Comment: Ну не надо сказок - не выводится. А что происходит? Монитор взрывается? Вот, смотрите: https://prnt.sc/1x608j1

Comment: "В вёрстке в разных местах" - так пишите другой вопрос, почему у вас в каком-то месте вёрстки не работает стандартная функция WP. Скорее всего потому, что всё сделано неправильно, и вы начинаете вывод вашей вёрстки без загрузки ядра WP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, да, всё выводится, сорри, - это у меня глюки. Принял Ваш ответ - для wordpress очевидно это оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Такие функции как date, strftime должны знать в каком часовом поясе вы их вызываете. Чтобы управлять часовым поясом, есть функция [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). Вордпрес скорее всего вызывает её и устанавливает в соответствии с конфигом сайта.

Разберитесь как вы теряете информацию о часовом поясе:

1. strtotime("2021-10-22 00:00+0300") вернёт метку времени -- абсолютное значение времени без часового пояса (больше у вас не московское время)
2. date('d.m', strtotime($date)) вернёт относительную дату с часовым поясом, будет использован часовой пояс по умолчанию (который может отличаться от того что в php.ini после вызова date_default_timezone_set)

```
<?php

$ts = strtotime('2021-10-22 00:00+0300');

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";
```

---

Я [загуглил](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+set+timezone), таймзона выставляется через админский интерфейс Settings -> Timezone. Убедитесь, что там у вас правильный часовой пояс.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться. А почему в Вашем примере выводится некорректное время? Сейчас в московском часовом поясе 14:00, а Ваш пример показывает полночь.

Comment: @Danila так я вывожу не текущее время, а полночь по Москве `strtotime('2021-10-22 00:00+0300');`.

Comment: _Убедитесь, что там у вас правильный часовой пояс_ - да, стоит Европа/Москва. Но я ради интереса попробовал задавать разные часовые пояса - никаких изменений.

Comment: А вот принудительное *date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');* в начале кода помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: Не надо с этим упражняться, в WP есть специальные функции для этого.

Comment: @KAGGDesign для чего этого? Уточните и скиньте ссылку на специальные функции.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин я ответ дал